# Xamarin Forms convertir nombre de color en Xamarin.Forms.Color

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017, color

veréis tengo un programa en el que leo un fichero xml, este indica opciones de posición y configuración de la pantalla. El objetivo es tener un lanzador automático que leyendo ese xml sepa los ajustes que debe configurar.
Cada xml es diferente al anterior, y en este también se indican colores de fondo, de texto o de borde, un campo que por ejemplo tiene el valor "Transparent" o el valor "Blue".

Se podría automatizar de algún modo la conversión de nombre de color a color? de momento lo hago con un switch pero hay tal cantidad de colores que me faltan muchos ya que no he encontrado ningún método que realice la conversion. Dejo mi código simple para que me entendais:

```
            switch (color)
            {
                case "Accent":
                    colorDevolver = Xamarin.Forms.Color.Accent;
                    break;
                case "AliceBlue":
                    colorDevolver = Xamarin.Forms.Color.AliceBlue;
                    break;
                case "Azure":
                    colorDevolver = Xamarin.Forms.Color.Azure;
                    break;
                case "Bisque":
                    colorDevolver = Xamarin.Forms.Color.Bisque;
                    break;
                case "Black":
                    colorDevolver = Xamarin.Forms.Color.Black;
                    break;
                case "Blue":
                    colorDevolver = Xamarin.Forms.Color.Blue;
                    break;
                case "BlueViolet":
                    colorDevolver = Xamarin.Forms.Color.BlueViolet;
                    break;
                case "BurlyWood":
                    colorDevolver = Xamarin.Forms.Color.BurlyWood;
                    break;
                case "Cyan":
                    colorDevolver = Xamarin.Forms.Color.Cyan;
                    break;
                case "DarkGray":
                    colorDevolver = Xamarin.Forms.Color.DarkGray;
                    break;
                case "DarkKhaki":
                    colorDevolver = Xamarin.Forms.Color.DarkKhaki;
                    break;
                case "DarkOrange":
                    colorDevolver = Xamarin.Forms.Color.DarkOrange;
                    break;
                case "DarkRed":
                    colorDevolver = Xamarin.Forms.Color.DarkRed;
                    break;
                case "DarkSeaGreen":
                    colorDevolver = Xamarin.Forms.Color.DarkSeaGreen;
                    break;
                case "DarkViolet":
                    colorDevolver = Xamarin.Forms.Color.DarkViolet;
                    break;
                case "DimGray":
                    colorDevolver = Xamarin.Forms.Color.DimGray;
                    break;
                case "DodgerBlue":
                    colorDevolver = Xamarin.Forms.Color.DodgerBlue;
                    break;
                case "FloralWhite":
                    colorDevolver = Xamarin.Forms.Color.FloralWhite;
                    break;
                case "Fuchsia":
                    colorDevolver = Xamarin.Forms.Color.Fuchsia;
                    break;
                case "Gainsboro":
                    colorDevolver = Xamarin.Forms.Color.Gainsboro;
                    break;
                case "GhostWhite":
                    colorDevolver = Xamarin.Forms.Color.GhostWhite;
                    break;
                case "Gray":
                    colorDevolver = Xamarin.Forms.Color.Gray;
                    break;
                case "Honeydew":
                    colorDevolver = Xamarin.Forms.Color.Honeydew;
                    break;
                case "HotPink":
                    colorDevolver = Xamarin.Forms.Color.HotPink;
                    break;
                case "Khaki":
                    colorDevolver = Xamarin.Forms.Color.Khaki;
                    break;
                case "Lavender":
                    colorDevolver = Xamarin.Forms.Color.Lavender;
                    break;
                case "LavenderBlush":
                    colorDevolver = Xamarin.Forms.Color.LavenderBlush;
                    break;
                case "LemonChiffon":
                    colorDevolver = Xamarin.Forms.Color.LemonChiffon;
                    break;
                case "LightBlue":
                    colorDevolver = Xamarin.Forms.Color.LightBlue;
                    break;
                case "LightCyan":
                    colorDevolver = Xamarin.Forms.Color.LightCyan;
                    break;
                case "LightCoral":
                    colorDevolver = Xamarin.Forms.Color.LightCoral;
                    break;
                case "LightGoldenrodYellow":
                    colorDevolver = Xamarin.Forms.Color.LightGoldenrodYellow;
                    break;
                case "LightGray":
                    colorDevolver = Xamarin.Forms.Color.LightGray;
                    break;
                case "LightGreen":
                    colorDevolver = Xamarin.Forms.Color.LightGreen;
                    break;
                case "LightSteelBlue":
                    colorDevolver = Xamarin.Forms.Color.LightSteelBlue;
                    break;
                case "Lime":
                    colorDevolver = Xamarin.Forms.Color.Lime;
                    break;
                case "MistyRose":
                    colorDevolver = Xamarin.Forms.Color.MistyRose;
                    break;
                case "Moccasin":
                    colorDevolver = Xamarin.Forms.Color.Moccasin;
                    break;
                case "NavajoWhite":
                    colorDevolver = Xamarin.Forms.Color.NavajoWhite;
                    break;
                case "OliveDrab":
                    colorDevolver = Xamarin.Forms.Color.OliveDrab;
                    break;
                case "Orange":
                    colorDevolver = Xamarin.Forms.Color.Orange;
                    break;
                case "PaleGoldenrod":
                    colorDevolver = Xamarin.Forms.Color.PaleGoldenrod;
                    break;
                case "PeachPuff":
                    colorDevolver = Xamarin.Forms.Color.PeachPuff;
                    break;
                case "Pink":
                    colorDevolver = Xamarin.Forms.Color.Pink;
                    break;
                case "Red":
                    colorDevolver = Xamarin.Forms.Color.Red;
                    break;
                case "RoyalBlue":
                    colorDevolver = Xamarin.Forms.Color.RoyalBlue;
                    break;
                case "Silver":
                    colorDevolver = Xamarin.Forms.Color.Silver;
                    break;
                case "SpringGreen":
                    colorDevolver = Xamarin.Forms.Color.SpringGreen;
                    break;
                case "Teal":
                    colorDevolver = Xamarin.Forms.Color.Teal;
                    break;
                case "Thistle":
                    colorDevolver = Xamarin.Forms.Color.Thistle;
                    break;
                case "Transparent":
                    colorDevolver = Xamarin.Forms.Color.Transparent;
                    break;
                case "Violet":
                    colorDevolver = Xamarin.Forms.Color.Violet;
                    break;
                case "Wheat":
                    colorDevolver = Xamarin.Forms.Color.Wheat;
                    break;
                case "White":
                    colorDevolver = Xamarin.Forms.Color.White;
                    break;
                case "WhiteSmoke":
                    colorDevolver = Xamarin.Forms.Color.WhiteSmoke;
                    break;
                case "Yellow":
                    colorDevolver = Xamarin.Forms.Color.Yellow;
                    break;
                case "InactiveBorder":
                    colorDevolver = Xamarin.Forms.Color.White;
                    break;
                default:
                    colorDevolver = Xamarin.Forms.Color.Transparent;
                    break;

            }
```

El objetivo seria convertir ese nombre del case al color apropiado de algún modo. Gracias.

Comment: Alguien conoce algún modo de automatizar ese switch para que venga el color que venga lo conozca?

Comment: Hasta donde yo se el switch lo vas a tener que hacer igualmente, lo que si puedes hacer, si estas usando Bindings, hacer un conversor que dado un string (nombre del color) devuelva el color, ponerle ese switch, y entonces podras bindear directamente el nombre del color al xaml, si te interesa te pongo el codigo.

Comment: Sinceramente me interesaría, ya que con el método que ves, hay veces que no tengo un color, y hasta que no veo que falla, no se que ese color falta. Pero si hubiera algún método de tener absolutamente controlado el código para todos los colores me vendría realmente bien. Al ser unos ejercicios dinámicos, no genero las pantallas en el xaml, hay pocos elementos fijos, por lo que la gran mayoría los creo en el código y los añado después como hijos de un layout.

Answer (score 0):

Como te decia en comentarios, si bien no te quitas el switch, si puedes hacer un conversor que te facilite tu uso en xaml con bindings.

Lo primero creas una clase del conversor, que se llame por ejemplo StringToColorConverter y que sea así:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Proyecto.Converters
{
    public class StringToColorConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            Color colorDevolver = Color.Transparent;
            if (value is string)
            {
                string color = (string)value;
                switch (color)
                {
                    case "Accent":
                        colorDevolver = Color.Accent;
                        break;
                    case "AliceBlue":
                        colorDevolver = Color.AliceBlue;
                        break;
                    case "Azure":
                        colorDevolver = Color.Azure;
                        break;
                    case "Bisque":
                        colorDevolver = Color.Bisque;
                        break;
                    case "Black":
                        colorDevolver = Color.Black;
                        break;
                    case "Blue":
                        colorDevolver = Color.Blue;
                        break;
                    case "BlueViolet":
                        colorDevolver = Color.BlueViolet;
                        break;
                    case "BurlyWood":
                        colorDevolver = Color.BurlyWood;
                        break;
                    case "Cyan":
                        colorDevolver = Color.Cyan;
                        break;
                    case "DarkGray":
                        colorDevolver = Color.DarkGray;
                        break;
                    case "DarkKhaki":
                        colorDevolver = Color.DarkKhaki;
                        break;
                    case "DarkOrange":
                        colorDevolver = Color.DarkOrange;
                        break;
                    case "DarkRed":
                        colorDevolver = Color.DarkRed;
                        break;
                    case "DarkSeaGreen":
                        colorDevolver = Color.DarkSeaGreen;
                        break;
                    case "DarkViolet":
                        colorDevolver = Color.DarkViolet;
                        break;
                    case "DimGray":
                        colorDevolver = Color.DimGray;
                        break;
                    case "DodgerBlue":
                        colorDevolver = Color.DodgerBlue;
                        break;
                    case "FloralWhite":
                        colorDevolver = Color.FloralWhite;
                        break;
                    case "Fuchsia":
                        colorDevolver = Color.Fuchsia;
                        break;
                    case "Gainsboro":
                        colorDevolver = Color.Gainsboro;
                        break;
                    case "GhostWhite":
                        colorDevolver = Color.GhostWhite;
                        break;
                    case "Gray":
                        colorDevolver = Color.Gray;
                        break;
                    case "Honeydew":
                        colorDevolver = Color.Honeydew;
                        break;
                    case "HotPink":
                        colorDevolver = Color.HotPink;
                        break;
                    case "Khaki":
                        colorDevolver = Color.Khaki;
                        break;
                    case "Lavender":
                        colorDevolver = Color.Lavender;
                        break;
                    case "LavenderBlush":
                        colorDevolver = Color.LavenderBlush;
                        break;
                    case "LemonChiffon":
                        colorDevolver = Color.LemonChiffon;
                        break;
                    case "LightBlue":
                        colorDevolver = Color.LightBlue;
                        break;
                    case "LightCyan":
                        colorDevolver = Color.LightCyan;
                        break;
                    case "LightCoral":
                        colorDevolver = Color.LightCoral;
                        break;
                    case "LightGoldenrodYellow":
                        colorDevolver = Color.LightGoldenrodYellow;
                        break;
                    case "LightGray":
                        colorDevolver = Color.LightGray;
                        break;
                    case "LightGreen":
                        colorDevolver = Color.LightGreen;
                        break;
                    case "LightSteelBlue":
                        colorDevolver = Color.LightSteelBlue;
                        break;
                    case "Lime":
                        colorDevolver = Color.Lime;
                        break;
                    case "MistyRose":
                        colorDevolver = Color.MistyRose;
                        break;
                    case "Moccasin":
                        colorDevolver = Color.Moccasin;
                        break;
                    case "NavajoWhite":
                        colorDevolver = Color.NavajoWhite;
                        break;
                    case "OliveDrab":
                        colorDevolver = Color.OliveDrab;
                        break;
                    case "Orange":
                        colorDevolver = Color.Orange;
                        break;
                    case "PaleGoldenrod":
                        colorDevolver = Color.PaleGoldenrod;
                        break;
                    case "PeachPuff":
                        colorDevolver = Color.PeachPuff;
                        break;
                    case "Pink":
                        colorDevolver = Color.Pink;
                        break;
                    case "Red":
                        colorDevolver = Color.Red;
                        break;
                    case "RoyalBlue":
                        colorDevolver = Color.RoyalBlue;
                        break;
                    case "Silver":
                        colorDevolver = Color.Silver;
                        break;
                    case "SpringGreen":
                        colorDevolver = Color.SpringGreen;
                        break;
                    case "Teal":
                        colorDevolver = Color.Teal;
                        break;
                    case "Thistle":
                        colorDevolver = Color.Thistle;
                        break;
                    case "Transparent":
                        colorDevolver = Color.Transparent;
                        break;
                    case "Violet":
                        colorDevolver = Color.Violet;
                        break;
                    case "Wheat":
                        colorDevolver = Color.Wheat;
                        break;
                    case "White":
                        colorDevolver = Color.White;
                        break;
                    case "WhiteSmoke":
                        colorDevolver = Color.WhiteSmoke;
                        break;
                    case "Yellow":
                        colorDevolver = Color.Yellow;
                        break;
                    case "InactiveBorder":
                        colorDevolver = Color.White;
                        break;
                    default:
                        colorDevolver = Color.Transparent;
                        break;
                }
            }
            return colorDevolver;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Despues hay que declararlo, como yo suelo usar los converters en mas de un sitio los declaro en app.xaml asi:

```
   <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>  
        <!--  CONVERTERS  -->
            <converters:StringToColorConverter x:Key="StringToColorConverter"/>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
```

Una vez hecho eso ya lo puedes usar en cualquier sitio. Imaginate por ejemplo que tienes un botón.

```
 <Button  
        BackgroundColor="{Binding Color, Converter={StaticResource StringToColorConverter}}"                 
        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
        Margin="50,0,50,20" />
```

Si el viewmodel tiene la propiedad `Color` con el string del texto, el botón sabra automaticamente de que color tiene que pintar el fondo.

Comment: me temo que esta funcionalidad ya la utilizaba, que si el color es conocido, ese color que devuelvo ya lo podía utilizar donde quisiera, el problema es que hay tal cantidad de colores, que para acaparar todos necesito un switch infinito, Ese es mi problema